# jquery validation not showing error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

This is my script code when I am running this code it is not showing any message it only showing red texbox for required field but i want to show error message below text box

```
(function ($, W, D) {
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function () {
            $("#register-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    FirstName: "required",
                    LastName: "required",
                },
                messages: {
                    FirstName: "Please enter your firstname",
                    LastName: "Please enter your lastname",
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $(D).ready(function ($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

this is my view code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default nobottommargin">
            <div class="panel-body" style="padding: 40px;">
                <div class="heading-block fancy-title nobottomborder title-bottom-border">
                    <h4>Registration</h4>
                </div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Registration", "Account"))
                                            {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
 //this is model binding in mvc                                                               
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: what exactly is asked here?

Comment: when i am running this code it is not showing  error message whatever i wrote like please enter first name it showing only red text box not message

Comment: it is not displaying any message

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "messages", new { @class = "text-danger" })    i have to write like this

Comment: is that an ASP.NET mvc project?

Comment: yes it is Asp.net mvc project

Comment: please help me I am new in this field

Comment: Why not just use `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` and decorate your proeprties with the `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: if i do like this it is server side validation if i define required field attribute i dont want server side

Comment: @sonubante What? Firstly what I have suggested does both client and server side validation (and with less code and without error!). And server side validation is critical. Client side validation is just a nice bonus and anyone can by-pass it. Never trust the user! You need to do some basic research.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **View** use

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

This will reference the jquery.validate javascript that will handle the client side validation.

In you **Model** class use the **[Required]** attribute for your class properties.

```
[Required]
public string FirstName{ get; set; }
```

Then inside your **Controller** 
Return the model if the ModelState is not valid/does not match your requirements.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
     return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> showing only red text box not message

That's because you've told it to only show custom errors and not to show property errors

Change

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

to

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

then you'll get the property errors in the summary box as well as in the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` - so you should remove those

### However

If you're not getting property errors in `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` either, then you've not wired up your validation for use with these two MVC helpers - you're expecting these to do something they don't do.

All validation should be **both** client-side and server-side.  By applying server side attributes (`[Required]` on the viewmodel) and using unobtrusive.js, you'll get both automatically, without needing to write everything twice.